# slapd not running

Tags: redhat, installation, openldap

I am new to Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3(Tikanga) as well as to open ldap.As openldap comes by default with the red hat.So i have installed berkeley database db-5.3.15.tar.gz

Version of already installed OpenLdap: openldap-2.3.43-3.el5

When I am running slapd by command:

service ldap start

It is showing

Starting slapd:                                            [  OK  ]

but no slapd process is starting. Please suggest what is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Any relevant log records?

Comment: where can i see the log?

Comment: besides this already installed openldap. I have installed both openldap and berkley db and tried to run it through slapd instead of service ldap start but that is also not running. Is it something like on red hat linux we can run openldap through "service ldap start" only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, are you sure its not running by checking the following commands;

You can check that the ldap is actually running by using the command `netstat -lntp | grep 389` and it should show something like this;

```
# netstat -lntp | grep 389
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      28783/slapd         
tcp        0      0 :::389                      :::*                        LISTEN      28783/slapd
```

If it is not running then try and start the command from the command line (so you can see any error messages to standard outout/error) like so;

```
# /usr/sbin/slapd -d 1
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.3.43 (Feb 22 2012 15:59:04) $
        mockbuild@builder10.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.3.43/openldap-2.3.43/build-servers/servers/slapd
daemon_init: listen on ldap:///
daemon_init: 1 listeners to open...
...
slapd starting
```

my log file seems to be located by default in `/var/log/slapd.log` , so that is the first place to look for additional information.

If it is definitely not starting, then you can edit the `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` file to increase the logging activity with [the loglevel command](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/#loglevel);

```
#<http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/#loglevel>
#loglevel 3333
#loglevel filter
#loglevel stats
#loglevel ACL
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. It really helped me.Can you please guide how can I change the default port?

Comment: put something like `SLAPD_OPTIONS="-h ldap://localhost:12345"` in `/etc/sysconfig/ldap`

Comment: there is no such directory/file named ldap i.e. i am only able to get /etc/openldap/ Inside this there is not ldap options. Any idea?

Comment: i have run the following command and it worked: slapd -h ldap://localhost:12345 -f usr/local/openldap_2.4/slapd.conf. But now i have another query how can i know which BDB it is referring as there are two bdb one is default and other is installed by me?

Comment: Its dependent on how you configured the additional root. I'd need to see the slapd.conf file. You can award this answer and paste the slapd.conf in another question and link to it here, and ill take a look.

Comment: I have raised another question: http://serverfault.com/questions/382893/how-to-know-which-berkley-db-openldap-is-refering-to  Please have a look and provide your suggestion.

Comment: re the `/etc/sysconfig/ldap`  its not there by default, but you can create it and the `service ldap start` script looks in that file for addition options. You can open the `/etc/init.d/ldap` in a text editor and search for the `/etc/sysconfig` and `SLAPD_OPTIONS` strings for details on how those values are used.

Comment: the filename is actually `/etc/sysconfig/slapd` instead of `/etc/sysconfig/ldap`